# How can I create a TFS build for a python project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, tfs, build

I already create different python project in Visual Studio using the Python Tools for Visual Studio: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/python/ now I installed TFS I started to use it as repository for my code.

Now multiple person will start to work on the same project.

I was readying about creating a build so you can track the different version of the code checked in but I'm not understanding how it works from the practical point of view.

Do I need just install a Build Agent for TFS or do I need do something specific for my python project?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "create a Python project in TFS"? TFS is a language-agnostic version-control system. You can hold anything there from plain text files to DVD images of the MPEG-encoded movies (although I strongly suggest against the latter). TFS also provide some additional services including build infrastructure and basing on https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1469 it seems there is some Python support there but I'm not sure how much

Comment: I suppose you already have (if not, create) a Team Project Collection, in it a Team Project. You then have two options, either create a [repo on tfs] (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/create-new-repo) and clone it with VS (or console git) and create your project within. The other option is to create a VS/python project and check the "add to source control" checkbox.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much, yes I create the project in my VM and I checked in in TFS, I wasn't sure if I had to create a build and for what the build is needed if just for continuous integration etc or something else but in this moment I'm ok with use TFS as repository without any other functionality. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create python project in VS. And import your local project into TFS source control system.

> **What is Team Foundation Server?**
>
> Team Foundation Server is Application Lifecycle Management to **manage
>   your product lifecycle**, reduce risks, and improve efficiencies. TFS include code, work, build, test ,release and many others which integrate with your existing IDE or editor thus enabling your cross-functional team to work effectively on software projects of all sizes.

In TFS, there is no python project or android or any other project template, you could **create a Team Project** holding the "traditional projects". And then add/import your local project in source control system(either **GIT** or **TFVC**). After this you could be able to share code, build apps, track work, and collaborate with team members. Details please refer this tutorial: [Connect to team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects)

As for build you could create a related definition to build your project and select your sln/project file holding by TFS in version control.

If you are really new to TFS, suggest you to go through this overview: [DevOps overview TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/vsts-tfs-overview)  covers all aspects of TFS which may help you to quickly start.